# Need help concat multiple fields into one based off of other fields

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I asked a similar question recently but, unfortunately, the nature of the request changed. Been looking at this code for a bit but my brain is friend and I can't quite think of a way to get this working as needed.

Working in SQL 2005 and this will encompass hundreds of values like this.

Thanks in advance!

Sample Table

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| ID |    CLASS    |  PARENT_ATTRIBUTE   |      ATTRIBUTE      |
+----+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Genre       | A                   | Hip Hop             |
|  1 | Genre       | B                   | Pop                 |
|  1 | Instruments | Keyboards           | Synth               |
|  1 | Instruments | Keyboards           | Grand Piano         |
|  1 | Instruments | Drums               | Kit                 |
|  1 | Moods       | Positive/Optimistic | Uplifting/Inspiring |
|  1 | Moods       | Positive/Optimistic | Happy/Feel Good     |
|  1 | Moods       | Musical Feel        | Pulsing             |
+----+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Desired Output

```
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| ID | MOODS                                                                                                    | INSTRUMENTS                                             |
| 1  |Positive/Optimistic - Uplifting/Inspiring, Positive/Optimistic -  Happy/Feel Good, Musical Feel - Pulsing | Keyboards - Synth, Keyboards - Grand Piano, Drums - Kit |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: you don't want a genre column?

Answer (score 0):

Using the trick with MAX and CASE WHEN to put the classes into columns:

```
SELECT ID,
MAX(CASE WHEN class = 'Instruments' THEN attribs END) as INSTRUMENTS,
MAX(CASE WHEN class = 'Moods' THEN attribs END) as MOODS,
MAX(CASE WHEN class = 'Genre' THEN attribs END) as GENRES
FROM (
    SELECT
    id, class, 
    STUFF ((
        SELECT ', ' + parent_attribute + ' - ' + attribute
        FROM   YourTable i
        WHERE  i.ID = o.ID AND i.CLASS = o.CLASS
        FOR XML PATH('') 
    ), 1, 2, '') AS attribs
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id, class FROM YourTable) o
) q
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;
```

Alternatively, using PIVOT on SQL Server 2008 or beyond:

```
select ID, 
[Instruments] as INSTRUMENTS,
[Moods] as MOODS,
[Genre] as GENRES
from (
    SELECT id, class,
    STUFF ((
        SELECT ', ' + parent_attribute + ' - ' + attribute
        FROM   YourTable i
        WHERE  i.ID = o.ID AND i.CLASS = o.CLASS
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '') AS attribs
    FROM (select distinct id, class from YourTable) o
) q
PIVOT (MAX(attribs) FOR class IN ([Instruments], [Moods], [Genre])
) pvt
order by id;
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe using PIVOT you can make this output, but i really don't  know how...

Check this link:
https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx